# Why is this equation regarding boson coherent states true?

Tags: bosons, second-quantization

I'm reading the proof of the closure for boson coherent states and it involves the following step:

$$
\int \prod_{\beta}\frac{\mathrm d \phi^*_{\beta} \mathrm d \phi_{\beta}}{2 \pi i} e^{-\sum_\beta \phi^*_\beta \phi_\beta} \left ( \phi_\alpha - {\partial \over \partial \phi^*_\alpha } \right )|\phi\rangle \langle \phi | = 0 
$$

Why is this true? $|\phi\rangle$ is a boson coherent state and $\phi_\alpha$ the eigenvalues of the annihilation operator $\hat a_\alpha$.

Comment: The product runs over which betas? The sum?
The state is independent on the integration variables? So is phi_alpha?